# How to find the time taken to send data across UDP

Tags: c++, udp, timer

I have a simple UDP client server written in C++ on Ubuntu 9.10 where the client sends a set to the server. How can I check how much time s it taking to sent it. I need to find the time from start of transfer to end.

Supposing my server and client are on the same machine then can I somehow save the system time and find the difference or something ?

Comment: define "time it's taking to send it". do you mean the time it takes for the sendto() call to return, the time it takes for the packet to leave your network interface card, the time it takes until it arrives at the server,...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking how long it takes for the packet to arrive at the server, there is no built in way to get that information.

If the server sends a reply, you can time how long it takes between sending the request and getting the reply and divide by 2 (not accurate, but a decent estimate).

Answer (score 1):

Setup the server to immediately send a reply to the client. At the client measure the round-trip time. The time you are looking for is half the round-trip time.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the time you sent the packet at in the beginning in every packet. In other words, you could create a custom header for all of your packets that would include this information.